# Exchange Server - Get CASMailbox - Parameters

Tags: exchange-server

When Running a Get CASMailbox command in the Exchange Management Shell, is there a parameter that will return a list of acttive and disabled mailboxes?

Answer (score 0):

This might serve your purpose if you haven't already found the answer:

```
Get-CASMailbox -Filter {HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership -eq $True -and DisplayName -notlike "CAS_{*"}
```